# OSX nginx 502 error on Magento

Tags: macos, magento, nginx, php

Hope you can help. I have Mac OSX Running Nginx and PHP-FPM and on some pages i am getting an nginx 502 error.

The error logs are less than helpful shall we say.

[error] 11939#0: *14 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:

I have added SOME of my conf files to git.
Could someone please have a look and let me know any tweaks I can make to stop my 502 error.

https://github.com/teuma86/my_conf

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue was todo with a known bug with PHP and Curl.

I found some errors on the OSX Console

Bug has been reported here.

http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1369/

A solution which worked for me

brew install curl --with-openssl 
brew install php53 --with-fpm --with-homebrew-openssl --with-homebrew-curl --without-snmp

Thanks for everyone who tried.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using APC cache? I was having the same issue and disabling APC seems to have worked